# An inequality of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

If $f(0)f(2) \ge f(1)^2$ and $g(0)g(2) \ge g(1)^2$, does it imply that 
$$
  (f(0)+g(0))(f(2)+g(2)) \ge (f(1)+g(1))^2
$$

I have figured out that this is equivalent to proving that:

$$f(2)g(0)+g(2)f(0) \ge 2f(1)g(1).$$ I can't find a counterexample to this, but I also can't think of a reason why it should always be true.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Cauchy-Swartz:
$$(f(0)+g(0))(f(2)+g(2))\ge\left(\sqrt{f(0)f(2)}+\sqrt{g(0)g(2)}\right)^2\ge(f(1)+g(1))^2$$

Comment: Very simple argument, I love it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$0\le(ad-bc)^2=(ad+bc)^2-4abcd$$

When everything is positive, this implies

$$2\sqrt{ab}\sqrt{cd}\le ad+bc$$

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Disregard, forgot about the squares.

It's not always true. For a counterexample, suppose

$f(0) = 2 = f(2)$ and $g(0) = 2 = g(2)$, while $f(1) = 4 = g(1)$.

Then the first inequalities hold, but

$$(f(0) + f(2))(g(0) + g(2)) = (2 + 2)(2 + 2) \not\geq (4 + 4)^2 = (f(1) + g(1))^2.$$

Comment: $f(0)f(2)\not\geq f(1)^2$. So your example does not satisfy the hypothesis of the question.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to show that $f(2)g(0)+g(2)f(0)\ge 2 f(1)g(1)$.

Say $x=g(1)f(2)$ and $y=f(1)g(2)$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(2)g(0)+g(2)f(0)&=&\frac{f(2)}{g(2)}\cdot g(0)g(2)+\frac{g(2)}{f(2)}\cdot f(0)f(2)\\
&\ge& \frac{f(2)}{g(2)}\cdot g(1)^2+\frac{g(2)}{f(2)}\cdot f(1)^2\\
&=&\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy}\cdot f(1)g(1)\\
&\ge& 2 f(1)g(1),\quad\text{(since $(x-y)^2\ge 0\implies \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy}\ge 2$).}
\end{eqnarray}
So the conclusion holds.